# Python, Threading with Tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

So I'm pretty deep into a program I am doing and I realized that with my program, I think I need to implement threading in some manner in order to stop it from locking up.

My program uses Tkinter for it's GUI, and when the program starts, I have a process that is running every second uses Tkinter's `after()` function.  The method in question reads data and appends it to a fixed length `deque()`.  In other parts of my program I have methods which read the last appended value, and process it.

My issue however is a simple loop that goes like this:

```
value = valDeque.getLastAppendedValue()
while value != "this specific value":
    value = valDeque.getLastAppendedValue()
```

When the inital variable call before the while loop sets `value` as something other than the specific value I am looking for the program goes into an endless loop and it seems everything else stops functioning.

I am assuming this is because the while loop keeps executing while my `after()` function that would append the value I am looking for is sitting in limbo waiting for it's turn to execute.  This is why I believe I need to use threading, since I can set up my update/append function to run separate of the rest of the processes so I don't have this error.

With that said, I am not super experienced with Python, and have no idea how to integrate threading with the Tkinter `after()` function since I know Tkinter's `mainloop()` doesn't interact with with something like `time.sleep()`.

I've tried looking online for some examples to get some headway, but I can't really make heads or tails or what I am finding.

Comment: _"I know Tkinter's mainloop() doesn't interact with with something like time.sleep()."_ If it helps, that rule of thumb only applies to single-threaded programs. You are completely permitted to call `sleep()` in one thread while `mainloop()` executes in another thread.

Comment: @Kevin So I could have my Deque updating class running in a separate thread updating every second with time.sleep while my main program runs off of the mainloop?  I did not know I could do this, and it definitely makes solving this issue a little easier.

Comment: @Skitzafreak The main thread is used for all GUI updates while the other threads are producer threads, some are blocked by I/O or doing some computation. `after` runs from the main thread's event processing loop `Tk.mainloop`.  The reason for limiting the main thread for GUI updates  is the lack of thread-safety in GUI toolkits. Any potentially long running or blocking operation must be spawned in a new thread so your GUI remains responsive to events.

Comment: @direprobs So essentially I can create external threads that interact with the program but only if they don't interfere with the GUI in any manner.  Am I interpreting your comment correctly?

Comment: @Skitzafreak, broadly speaking, that's the idea. Tkinter tends to crash with mysterious errors if you try to access any of its objects directly in a thread other than the one that imported Tkinter in the first place. An indirect message passing layer, such as a queue or deque, should insulate you from that kind of trouble.

Comment: @Skitzafreak Yes.