# python thread data manipulation

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am trying to manipulate some data in a thread from the main function. The issue I am facing about modifying some of the variables which are part of the function which is running on a thread.

So I am trying to run a Tkinter based GUI loop in a thread to ensure it is always running. And want to modify some of the label corresponding to the status in the main function execution. I am facing an issue where it is unable to locate the label variables in the main loop as it is part of the function running on the thread.

Below is a simplified psuedo code for that approach. Please suggest if this a correct way to the above task or is there is any better and efficient way.

```py
import threading

def thread_func():
    i = 0
    while True:
        print('i from thread: ', i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = threading.Thread(target=thread_func)
    t.start()
    
    while True:
        i += 1
```

Actual scaled down simplified code

```py
import threading
import tkinter as tk

def gui():
    window = tk.Tk()
    label = tk.Label(text='On')
    label.pack()
    window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = threading.Thread(target=gui)
    t.start()
    
    while True:
        label['text'] = 'Active'
```

Error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    label['text'] = 'Active'
NameError: name 'label' is not defined
```

Is there a better way to keep the tkinter gui always on and perform some task in the loop?

Comment: Is your code working for your question?

Comment: Code is not working as it gives me an error, updating the error in the question and also fixing the import library name

Comment: You can use the `global` keyword (not recommended), or create a class and declare `label` within the `__init __` function: `self.label = tk.Label (text = 'on')`

Comment: @Deep Don't use threads when using `tkinter` unless you know the risks. I have seen `tkinter` crash python (without a traceback) when `tkinter` is used from multiple threads. Look at `.after` scripts to schedule calls to your functions.

Comment: @TheLizzard Then which is the right and better way to have tkinter and some loop in the same code?

Comment: @Deep Use `.after` scripts. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67738164/11106801) for an example where I implemented a `tkinter` friendly loop.

Answer (score 1):

When you write code of label there then you will get error because when program start it starts from creating thread, that thread will only end when tkinter window is close and same for previous `thread_fuc` code. And you wrote the label code after tkinter window is closed.

The above issue will be solved by doing this :

```
import threading

def thread_func():
    while True:
        print('i from thread: ', i)

def tt():
    global i
    while True:
        i += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    i=0
    t = threading.Thread(target=thread_func)
    t.start()
    yt = threading.Thread(target=tt)
    yt.start()
```

Making `i` global and running 2 function parallely. We have to `global` because we can't use the variable of one function to another. And additionally we are running 2 function in 2 thread.

And for your `tkinter` file as @TheLizzard suggest, you can use `.after` insted of using thread in `tkinter` if you want to change content constantly/want to use loop.
Here's the basic example how you can implement it:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk

app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry("200x220")

label = tk.Label(app, text="0")
label.pack()

def change(b=0):
    if b < 30:
        a = random.randrange(1, 7, 1)
        label.config(text=a)
        app.after(100, change, b+1)

b1 = tk.Button(app, text="Get New Number", command=change)
b1.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

For more explanation about it you may visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67738164/12446721).

Comment: Still getting the same error: 
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    label.config(text= 'Active')
NameError: name 'label' is not defined
```

Comment: @Deep is last edit clear, why are you using threading there?

Comment: Yeah that is clear, but then what is a better and efficient way to perform the task which I want? Is there any other approach apart from threading to keep gui on and have an ability to modify something in the loop?

Comment: I don't want to use thread if there's a way to keep the gui running continously while I am having another loop performing some task to update the status on the gui. I am not aware of any other approach, so if you can help me with any hints or suggestion that would be much helpful.

Comment: I understand, what your are trying to do in loop question but didn't understand in tkinter question @Deep

Comment: For tkinter threading probably [python threading with tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45698523/python-threading-with-tkinter) is the answer and solution is probably [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-thread-in-tkinter-python), [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-thread-in-tkinter-python/)

Comment: tkinter needs to have `<>.mainloop()` to have the gui running, which would block the execution of the main flow. So anything you do after that won't show up on the gui. Also if there is a continuous loop before `'<>.mainloop()` then it won't let the gui respond to any changes

Comment: Checked everything, including the link to another answer. But that doesn't solve my issue. So here I am hoping if you know any other better way for this task that would be helpful.

Comment: Isn't `thread_func` problem solved? @Deep

Comment: @Xitiz Right now you have a race condition. In rare cases the `tt` function might be called before the `thread_func` function giving you an error because `i` wouldn't be defined.

Comment: @TheLizzard I have defined `i` before any threading starts. I hope this will not give any error. When that rare case happened, I have defined `i` in the first line of the `thread_fun` which will run as soon as that function is called.

Comment: @Xitiz That should be fine now. Also you don't need the `global i` inside `thread_func` as it doesn't do anything. You need to use `global` when you are changing the variable. When reading a global variable you don't need to use `global`.

Comment: Edited! You haven't explained that mine question. @TheLizzard, can I add that `.after()` script in my answer?

Comment: Yes you can. I actually thing the answer will be simpler with `.after` scripts.

Comment: I have edited check if it right or not? @TheLizzard

Comment: Looks great. Now I will have to upvote the answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Using class and threading:

```py
import tkinter


class Test(tkinter.Label):

    x = False

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pack()
        self['text'] = 'On'

    def gui(self):
        if not self.x:
            self['text'] = 'Active'
            self.mainloop()
        else:
            self.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    label = Test()
    while isinstance(label, Test):
        t = threading.Thread(target=label.gui())
        t.start()
```

Comment: If we aren't using threading then I don't think there is an issue, the main issue is thread and you removed it!

Comment: Right now you are calling `label.gui()` then passing the result as `target` to `threading.Thread`. So `label.gui` doesn't run in a new thread.